# How do you unit test HTTP Response/Requests in c# controller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I am trying to unit test a c# controller method.  I have looked up many questions and nothing quite gives me instructions on how to unit test the API controller.  The code that is correct is below for the method.  How do you unit test for the brackets.

I have figured out how to test the method "Reverse Payment", but I am using moq and xunit to test the actual c# method. This is my current unit test:

```cs
    public class PaymentsControllerTests : BackOfficeIntegrationTestBase
    {
        private readonly CurrentDateProvider _currentDateProvider;
        [BackOfficeRolesAuthorize(BackOfficeUserRole.Admin, BackOfficeUserRole.CSR, BackOfficeUserRole.DealerSupportRep,
            BackOfficeUserRole.CSRManager)]

        [Fact]
        public async Task AdminReversalPermissions()
        {
            IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
            var mediator = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IMediator>>();
            var currentDateProvider = fixture.Freeze<CurrentDateProvider>();
            var mockRepo = new Mock<IMediator>();
            var controller = new PaymentsController(mockRepo.Object);

            // Setup Dependencies
            //DataContext dataContext = SetUpDatabase(fixture);

            ReversePaymentSetup(fixture, mediator);


            var result = await controller.ReversePayment(LeaseInfo.ApplicationId, 100);



            var viewResult = result as NoContentResult;
            Assert.NotNull(viewResult);

        }


        private void ReversePaymentSetup(IFixture fixture, Mock<IMediator> mediator)
        {
            PaymentData data = new PaymentData();

            //Mock the mediator
            var paymentPlan = new Data.Model.PaymentPlan()
            {
                LeaseId = 1,
                LeaseTerm = LeaseTerm.Year,
                DefermentDays = 5,
                FirstPaymentDate = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2019", "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                StoreState = "VA"
            };

            var responseData = new BuildPaymentPlanResponse();
            responseData.Data = new BuildPaymentPlanResponse.InitializePaymentPlanResponseData()
            {
                PaymentPlan = paymentPlan
            };
            PaymentStatusChangeManualRequest request = fixture.Build<PaymentStatusChangeManualRequest>()
                                                              .With(x => x.PaymentPlanId, LeaseInfo.ApplicationId)
                                                              .With(x => x.PaymentId, 100)
                                                              .With(x => x.Status, PaymentStatus.Reversed)
                                                              .Create();

            Assert.Equal(PaymentStatus.Reversed, request.Status);
            Assert.Equal(100, request.PaymentId);
            Assert.NotNull(LeaseInfo.ApplicationId);

        }
    }
}
```

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
        [HttpPut("{paymentId}/ReversePayment")]
        [BackOfficeRolesAuthorize(BackOfficeUserRole.Admin, BackOfficeUserRole.CSR, BackOfficeUserRole.DealerSupportRep,
            BackOfficeUserRole.CSRManager)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ReversePayment(int paymentPlanId, int paymentId)
        {
            await _mediator.Send(new PaymentStatusChangeManualRequest
            {
                PaymentPlanId = paymentPlanId,
                PaymentId = paymentId,
                Status = PaymentStatus.Reversed
            });

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'unit test for the brackets'? Anyway, you have unit test for the controller, what do you think you are missing here?

Comment: The part for [ProducesResponseType] and HttpPut, how do you unit test these?

Comment: Firstly, why do you think you need to test attributes? Secondly, the `ProducesResponseType` attribute claims your method returns a `NotFound` status but the code doesn't do that at all.